# Facebook App Events crashing app

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to use the facebook app event for search as outlined in this documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android#events

I implemented my search App event as such:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_SEARCHED, query);
logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_SEARCHED,parameters);
```

When I open my app to test and execute the search method that this above code resides in I get these errors on my force close:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:259)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4762)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19795)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:255)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4762)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19795)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'context' cannot be null
       at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
       at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.java:616)
       at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.newLogger(AppEventsLogger.java:356)
       at com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.Search.<init>(Search.java:40)
       at com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.MainDrawer2.goToSearch(MainDrawer2.java:297)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:255)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4762)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19795)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
```

And:

```
thread
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:259)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
       at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4762)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19795)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
```

Comment: How are you creating the logger instance? It looks like the Context you pass in is null.

Comment: AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(getActivity());

Comment: So I had this outside the onClick, at the start of the method. Moved it into the onclick and now its not crashing. Not sure why....